# no input fields, only submit button appearing django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

My input field isn't appearing, but my submit button is and I'm not getting an error. Why isn't it showing up with a label in my browser. Also if I want to use the ModelForm class with a Foreign key from the User model do I have to import it into forms.py? Let me know if there is any other information you need. I'm stuck.

project = CMIRS
app = error_tracking

**search_incidents.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<p>Not only have you successfully logged in, you have also made it to the Search Incidents page!</p>
<br><br>

<form action="error_tracking.views.search_usernames" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
import datetime

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from error_tracking.models import Incident
from error_tracking.forms import IncidentForm

@login_required
def search_incidents(request):
    incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_time_reported')
    return render(request, 'search_incidents.html', { 
        'incident_list' : incident_list,
        'user' : request.user
    })

def search_usernames(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = IncidentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = IncidentForm()
    return render_to_response('error_tracking/search_incidents.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from error_tracking.models import Incident

class IncidentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = ['user_id']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Incident(models.Model):
       incident_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       incident_date_time_reported = models.DateTimeField('incident reported', default=timezone.now)
       user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
       incident_date_time_occurred = models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now)
       clinical_sample = models.BooleanField(default=True)
       number_of_clinical_samples = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       sample_id_numbers = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
       incident_category = models.ForeignKey(Incident_Category)
       technician = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       action_taken = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

       def __str__(self):
               return self.incident_id

       class Meta:
               verbose_name_plural="Incident"
```

**error_tracking/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'error_tracking.views.search_incidents'),
]
```

Comment: You have duplicate URL patterns...

Comment: fixed. I still can't get the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! `form` needed to be declared under `search_incidents` and passed back to search_incidents.html

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def search_incidents(request):
    form = IncidentForm()
    incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_time_reported')
    return render(request, 'search_incidents.html', { 
        'incident_list' : incident_list,
        'user' : request.user,
        'form' : form
    })
```